# How to find discount rate value if total present value and future time series of cash flows is known in Python

Tags: python, numpy, finance, polynomials

While going through an [article](http://people.stern.nyu.edu/adamodar/podcasts/valUGspr21/session6slides.pdf), I encountered a situation where I encountered below polynomial equation.

For reference, below is the equation.

```
15446 = 537.06/(1+r) + 612.25/(1+r)**2 + 697.86/(1+r)**3 + 795.67/(1+r)**4 + 907.07/(1+r)**5
```

This is discount cash flow time series values which we use in finance to get the idea of present value of future cash flows after applying the appropriate discount rate.

So from above equation, I need to calculate the variable `r` in python programming environment?. I do hope that there must be some library which can be used to solve such equations?.

I solve this, I thought to use the [numpy.npv](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.npv.html) API.

```
import numpy as np
presentValue = 15446
futureValueList = [537.06, 612.25, 697.86,795.67, 907.07]
// I know it is not possible to get r from below. Just put
// it like this to describe my intention.
presentValue = np.npv(r, futureValueList)
print(r)
```

Comment: use a binary search algorithm, or use Newton's algorithm to find a zero point of a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply your NPV formula with the highest power or `(1+r)` and then find the roots of the polynomial with [`polyroots`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyroots.html) (just take the only real root and disregard the complex ones):

```
import numpy as np

presentValue = 15446
futureValueList = [537.06, 612.25, 697.86,795.67, 907.07]

roots = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyroots(futureValueList[::-1]+[-presentValue])
r = roots[np.argwhere(roots.imag==0)].real[0,0] - 1
print(r)
#-0.3332398877886278
```

---

As it turns out the formula given is incomplete, see p. 14 of the linked article. The correct equation can be solved with standard optimization procedures, e.g. [`optimize.root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html) providing a sensible initial guess:

```
from scipy import optimize

def fun(r):
    r1 = 1 + r
    return 537.06/r1 +  612.25/r1**2 + 697.86/r1**3 + 795.67/r1**4 + 907.07/r1**5 * (1 + 1.0676/(r-.0676)) - 15446

roots = optimize.root(fun, [.1])
print(roots.x if roots.success else roots.message)
#[0.11177762]
```

Comment: The real root need not be unique, e.g. `presentValue = 10; futureValueList = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

Comment: Math aside, constant negative discount rates seem weird. A bond that pays a dollar each year would have infinite price.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem you're perfectly right of course in both comments. I just answered the OP's question of how to find `r` in the given formula, assuming that the formula makes sense in the given context and hence has a unique real solution. I now looked at the linked presentation and it turns out (page 14) that the equation in the question above is incomplete.

Comment: I did not mean to criticize your (perfectly correct) answer. If someone asks how to run `sudo rm -rf  /`, some disclaimer may be helpful. I think the same concern is applicable here.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem: no worries :), I just edited the answer.